# How to print the difference only in hours,minutes and seconds only (like td = 33:23:21) in Python?

Tags: python-2.7

```
import Datetime

str1 = "2017-05-01 18:23:22" #String one of time
str2 = "2017-05-02 23:16:22" #String two of time

#Turning it to datetime objects

T1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
T2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(str2, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

DIFF = T2 -T1
print DIFF
```

Output is as: 1 day, 4:53:00
Needed outout: 28:53:00

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go, add this to the bottom of your code to print out the desired format:

```
days = DIFF.days
hours, remainder = divmod(DIFF.seconds, 3600)
minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)

print str(days * 24 + hours) + ":" + str("%02d" % minutes) + ":" + str("%02d" % seconds)
```